# What gets copied (and what doesn't) during a Target Mode copy?

Tags: recovery, migration

I recently cloned my old, dying computer into a new one, using **Target Mode** and a Firewire 800 cable via **Recovery Mode**.
Everything looked perfectly identical. I launched Safari on the new computer, and all the tabs I was browsing were there.
But when I opened Chrome, there were no tabs open, and the extensions were uninstalled.
I'm trying to understand what happened, and where these files were copied for Target Mode to omit them.

**Which files does Target Mode copy - and which files does it not copy - when cloning a hard drive with Recovery Mode?**

Comment: What did you clone it with?

Answer (score 2):

Target Disk Mode just turns the whole Mac into an external drive. There's essentially no difference between doing that and taking the drive out and putting it in a FireWire drive enclosure.

There's nothing special about TDM that makes it not-copy certain files.

However, when using a cloning app, some files may or may not be included. These are usually just 'temporary' data, such as caches, or machine-specific files that the system will recreate if absent. There may be options in the cloning app to exclude other files.